# Eclipse, JAR Export is packaging svn files

Tags: java, eclipse, svn

How can I stop this from happening, it is grabbing files in .svn folders when I create jars. The .svn folder is unchecked in the prompt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you try (after this [blog entry](http://www.bennybottema.com/2009/08/11/repost-make-eclipse-ignore-svn-directories/))

```
Window -> Preferences, Java -> Compiler -> Building.  
Under “Output folder” add “, `.svn/`” to “Filtered Resources” (so that you get “`*.launch, .svn/`”).
```

The problem could come from the fact a Jar exporter includes the option:

```
"export generated class files and resources"
                                  ^^^^^^^^^
```

[image]

If you filter out those "resources" (the `.svn` folders), chances are they won't be included in the final Jar.